# Pause all threads for a specific duration in regular interval in Jmeter

Tags: performance, timer, jmeter, load-testing

I have a thread group with
`No. of users: 3`
`Ramp up period: 2`
`Loop count: forever`

`Having single Http request`

My requirement is to pause all threads for 1 minute at regular interval of 30 minutes.
I tried think time, and other timers as well but it doesn't work.

My Jmeter version is 5.1.1

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) to your Test Plan and set its "Runtime (seconds)" to `1800`

   [image]
2. Put your HTTP Request sampler as a child of the Runtime Controller
3. Add [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler after the Runtime Controller and set it to "Pause" for `60000` milliseconds

   [image]

---

Just in case be informed that [as per JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter-5.2/) (or to the latest stable version from [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) as soon as possible

Comment: I followed the steps mentioned above, but it doesn't pause the threads, seems to work as before without any pause.

Comment: I added listener, `View Results in Table` which displays the start time of each requests. And also from the API metrics.

Comment: It works fine now, I put inappropriate value for `Runtime controller` as its in seconds, coz of it Jmeter finishes all the request before pause the thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ultimate Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-ultimate-thread-group-regex-extractor-and-json-path-extractor-apache-jmeter/) to simulate that, but threads will exit the iteration and start a new one after 1 minute (not a pause).

[image]